# FTP File upload powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

WebClient.UploadFile: $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient $client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password") $client.UploadFile("ftp://ftp:50000/test.zip", "C:\HML-V-DC.zip")

When using this script on one computer I am able to upload a file directly to my FTP serve without any issues

But when running this on another machine in another location I get an error "You cannot call a null-valued expression"

Powershell version on computer that is not working: PSVersion                      5.1.14393.3866

Powershell version on computer that is working: PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1

- WebClient.UploadFile: $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient $clie ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

Was hoping someone with some quick insight may be able to help me understand what I am missing here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove "WebClient.UploadFile: " from the line

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
```